# compare two lists in python containing strings

Tags: python, list, string-comparison

Comparison between these two lists and eliminating from `List1` if it matches. Is there any way to process the `List1` too.

```
List1: ["'file',", "'ist',", "'customer',"]

List2: ['permission', 'ist', 'dr']
```

Comment: What do you mean by process the list?

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: processing List means List1 to ['file', 'ist', 'customer'] to make processing easier. @S

Comment: expected output should eliminate 'ist' from list1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a simple list comprehension would do it.

```
filtered_list = [string for string in List1 if string not in List2]
```

Warning: your strings in List1 don't match the format of the strings in List2. Not sure if that was your intent. The string `'ist',` won't match with the string `ist`.

Comment: for what it's worth this isn't the most efficient as it's O(n^2) running time

Comment: actually i know to do comparison, the format of the list1 is creating problem. How to handle that.

Comment: The cleanest approach would probably be creating a new list with the strings cleaned up. `str.strip` might do it, depending on what other formatting errors are in those strings. `cleaned_list_1 = [x.strip(['"', "'", ',']) for x in List1]`

Comment: @Tnguyen True. It would run in O(n) if he used set(List2) and searched in the set instead of in List2 directly.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the required output.

```
for i in list(List1):
    if i.strip("',") in List2:
        List1.remove(i)
```

Comment: You are just so awesome.. was stuck at it from morning.. brilliant!! thanks!!